# How to send email with Tests statistics like Total Tests: 10, Failed: 2, Passed: 8, Skipped:0

Tags: jenkins, testng

I am using  Maven+TestNG auto-tests run by Jenkins. How do i display the test statistics in the email notification Jenkins sends.

I would like something like this:

Results:
Total Tests: 10, Passed: 8, Failed: 2, Skipped:0

Comment: Which mail plugin are you using? Have you tried: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin ?

Comment: am using email-ext+plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by using using Email Extension Plugin and one of the email template. See attachment.
[image]

Comment: Hi Ahmed,Unable to see posted image,can you please provide proper example with steps and code so that it is very easy to understand.